# jQuery Accordion: Disable expand on header click, assign to link

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, accordion

Is there a way to disable a sections expansion from the header click, and instead assign the functionality to a link included in the header? The idea is to have a button on the left of the header expand and collapse the header. My hope is that this would allow me to include other elements in the header that would be clickable without expanding/collapsing. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/b8vGH/) is a way to do it. Basicly, I'm initializing accordion with `disable` option and binding `click` events which first enables accordion, then do the accordion thing and lastly disables accordion.

HTML:

```
<div class="demo">
  <div id="accordion">
    <h3>
        <a href="#">Section 1</a>
        <a href="#" data-index="0" class="trigger">Expand this</a>
    </h3>
    <div>
      <p>
        Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
        ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
        amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo
        ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
      </p>
    </div>
    <h3>
        <a href="#">Section 2</a>
        <a href="#" data-index="1" class="trigger">Expand this</a>
    </h3>
    <div>
      <p>
        Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
        purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
        velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit
        faucibus urna.
      </p>
    </div>
    <h3>
        <a href="#">Section 3</a>
        <a href="#" data-index="2" class="trigger">Expand this</a>
    </h3>
    <div>
      <p>
        Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
        Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
        ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia
        ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          List item one
        </li>
        <li>
          List item two
        </li>
        <li>
          List item three
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>
        <a href="#">Section 4</a>
        <a href="#" data-index="3" class="trigger">Expand this</a>
    </h3>
    <div>
      <p>
        Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
        malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus
        orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel
        est.
      </p>
      <p>
        Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
        Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
        inceptos himenaeos.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({ disabled: true });
    $(".trigger").click(function() {
        $("#accordion").accordion("enable").accordion("activate", parseInt($(this).data("index"), 10)).accordion("disable");
    });
});
```

Comment: And if you don't want to use `data-index` you can find index from header and use it like this: `$("#accordion").accordion("enable").accordion("activate", $("#accordion h3").index($(this).parent())).accordion("disable");`

Comment: When I replaced the "#" in "<a href="#">Section 1</a>" with an url to an other page like "<a href="http://google.com">Section 1</a>" the link was not activated. The solution, for me, was to replace the href with an onclick='window.open("http://google.com");'.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply [specify your header element](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-header):

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ header: 'h3' });
```

Comment: AFAIK, header element is not just about what triggers open/close action. It also defines what stays visible after collapse. Thus having redefined the header to smth else we disable trigger on click (as we wish) but also get the real header hidden when collapsed (not wanted).

Comment: It is also required to have the content element as an immediate sibling after the element defined as header. This will not fit the case in question as the link won't be next to the content element (obviously having some wrapper div). IMO

Answer (score 2):

A better way is to unbind the click handler:

```
    $(function () {
      $("#accordionId").accordion({
         collapsible: true,
         active: false,
         animate: 0,
         icons: false
      });

      $(".ui-accordion-header").unbind('click').click(function() {
         alert('dsds');
      });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

As above. 
If you are only using one accordion or having the same functionality/interface I would usually edit the actual java script file 
eg. [jquery.accordion](http://jquery.bassistance.de/accordion/jquery.accordion.js) 
I would edit the default settings near the bottom of the file from 'header: "a"' to something like 'header: "acc-heading"'

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the most elegant way is to set the event to *none* while initializing the accordion:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
  event: "none"
});
```

Then one is able to trigger the section from code:

```
$("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", 0);
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/pzwj849m/)

Please note, if you use the older jq-ui version you may need to use the older method - *activate* (instead of *"option", "active"*)